# Diffusion on a Manifold in Local Coordinates $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ij}\partial_j\right)u$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

In my partial differential equations class, my instructor mentioned generalizations of diffusion to non-Euclidean space. As I understand, one may use the Laplace-Beltrami operator on a smooth Riemannian manifold $\mathcal M$ of dimension $n$ to state a local notion of diffusion.

$$\Delta_{\mathcal M} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|} g^{ij} \partial_j \right)$$

If the manifold $\mathcal M$ has an atlas of charts $\{(U_{\alpha}, \varphi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal A}$ wherein $\varphi_\alpha : \mathcal M \supseteq U_\alpha \to \mathbb R ^ n$, then define $\varphi_\alpha (U_\alpha) = \Omega \subseteq \mathbb R ^ n$ s.t. $\varphi_{\alpha}^{-1} : \Omega \to U_\alpha$ is a $C^{\infty}$ mapping.

I wish to cast the diffusion equation on $\mathcal M$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \Delta _ { \mathcal M} u$$

with a solution $u(t, \vec \xi) : [0, \infty) \times \mathcal M \to \mathbb R$ as a more complicated equation on $\Omega$. (I may be missing a sign in front of my Laplacian.) I further assume that the source of heat is contained within $U_{\alpha}$ and that my model shall only be valid as long as all of the diffused quantity also remains within $U_{\alpha}$.

How can I directly write the PDE for $u \circ \varphi_\alpha ^ {-1} : \Omega \to \mathbb R$? I was thinking of defining $\vec \eta : \Omega \to U_\alpha$ by $\vec \eta = \varphi_{\alpha}^{-1}$ and applying the chain rule in the definition of the Laplace-Beltrami operator. In particular, does the function $v(t, \vec x) = u(t, \vec \eta(\vec x)) : [0, \infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb R$ obey the following equation in more classical notation

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(g(\eta(\vec x)))}} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(\sqrt{\det g (\eta(\vec x))} \sum_{j=1}^n g(\eta(\vec x))_{ij}^{-1} \frac{\partial u(t, \eta (\vec x))}{\partial x_j}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(g(\vec \eta(\vec x)))}} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(\sqrt{\det g (\vec \eta(\vec x))} \sum_{j=1}^n g(\vec \eta(\vec x))_{ij}^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_k} \Bigr|_{(t, \vec \eta(\vec x))} \frac{\partial \eta_k}{\partial x_j}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(g(\vec \eta(\vec x)))}} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(\sqrt{\det g (\vec \eta(\vec x))} g(\vec \eta(\vec x))_{ij}^{-1} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_k} \Bigr|_{(t, \vec \eta(\vec x))} \frac{\partial \eta_k}{\partial x_j}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(g(\vec \eta(\vec x)))}} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(\sqrt{\det g (\vec \eta(\vec x))} g(\vec \eta(\vec x))_{ij}^{-1} \right) \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_k} \Bigr|_{(t, \vec \eta(\vec x))} \frac{\partial \eta_k}{\partial x_j} \\
&+ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n
g(\vec \eta(\vec x))_{ij}^{-1} \left(
\sum_{l = 1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_k \partial \xi_l} \Bigr|_{(t, \vec \eta(\vec x))} \frac{\partial \eta_k}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial \eta_l}{\partial x_i} +
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_k} \Bigr|_{(t, \vec \eta(\vec x))} \frac{\partial^2 \eta_k}{\partial x_j \partial x_i} 
\right)
\end{align*}
$$

where $g : \mathcal M \to \mathbb R ^ {n \times n }$ is a function returning the matrix form of the metric tensor at a given point on the manifold.

I could have very well mixed up which coordinates are which making all of the above would be incorrect. (I don't have very much experience with Riemannian geometry -- only a little knowledge of differential forms.)
Despite the fact that the derivatives on the right hand side are in $u$, could the above be recast as an equation in $v$?

If on the off chance that the above equation is actually correct, is the PDE linear? (The coefficients depending on the derivatives of $\eta$ would in general be variable and nonlinear, but the dependence on $u$ would still remain linear, right?)

Comment: Your formula for the Laplacian is already in terms of a coordinate chart. Isn't what you want just $$\partial u/\partial t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|} g^{ij} \partial_j u \right)?$$  You can interpret this with $u$ a function on $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$, $\partial_i$ the usual Euclidean partial derivatives and $g$ the coefficients of the metric tensor in this chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the PDE is linear, which is already apparent from the form $\partial_t u = \Delta_Mu$, since $\partial_t - \Delta_M$ is a linear differential operator.

To find the coordinatized expression of the PDE, you are correct in that you just need to apply the chain rule appropriately in your given chart. That the PDE is linear is also apparent from the coordinate expression because it has the form $$\partial_t u(t, \eta(x)) = h_0(\eta(x))u(t,\eta(x)) + h_1(\eta(x))Du(t,\eta(x)) + h_2(\eta(x))D^2u(t,\eta(x)).$$ The notation I'm using is just shorthand for the cumbersome coordinate expression, which in its essence is a sum of a term involving no derivatives of $u\circ\eta$, a term involving first derivatives of $u\circ\eta$ and a term involving second derivatives. The reason this is a linear equation in $u$ is because composing with $\eta$, multiplying by fixed functions of $x$, and taking derivatives are all linear operations.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I agree that all operators are linear, but I'm having a hard time convincing my intuition that even on an extremely curved manifold that diffusion will remain a linear process. Could I try to justify it by the fact that the "Brownian motion" of a particle over the surface of the manifold is a sufficiently local process as to not be changed by the curvature? The equation $\partial_t v(t, x) = h_0(x) v(t, x) + h_1(x)Dv(t,x) + h_2(x)Dv(t,x)$ should be solvable over any polygonal domain in $\mathbb R ^ n$ using the Fokas method, right?

Comment: In my first comment, I got rid of the $\eta$ in the definition of $h_0$, $h_1$, and $h_2$ because I thought that they were all dummy functions. Does your formula essentially imply that we can forget about the underlying manifold by solving a more general problem in Euclidean space? That was my principle interest in the first question. I don't have enough experience to describe the diffusion process on the manifold itself, but if there was a way to locally realize it in $\mathbb R ^ n$, I was curious if standard methods could be applied to solve it.

Comment: @Talmsmen: Sure, you could try and convince yourself of the linearity by considering Brownian motion, but it's much simpler than that. After all, what is your definition of a "linear process" other than one driven by a linear equation? And yes, once you consider the equation in a coordinate chart, it becomes some linear PDE with variable coefficients on $\mathbb R^n$, and then you could use whatever tools you know about in $\mathbb R^n$ to approach it (interior estimates, Strichartz estimates, and so on...)